# How can I improve Java application load / startup/ boot time on Websphere 8.5?

Tags: jvm, websphere, startup, boot, websphere-8

I need a solution to bring up java applications on IBM Websphere faster. I looked up material on IBM website. The suggested jvm flag -XQuickStart but that flag seems to emulate -client so won't be useful in production.

What are the other ways that in which on can improve/lower boot times for applications deployed via ear files on Websphere 8.5? Please consider both JDK 7 and 8 when giving suggestions.

Comment: Only the applications or do you mean the entire WebSphere server?

Comment: Entire Websphere server. Application tuning is a separate topic in this case.

Comment: One thing I have found could improve load times dramatically is to make sure you have fast SSD disks. I have seen load times go from 15 minutes to one minute just by changing disks. Other things is of course to do less initializations of your applications and startup (and do them during runtime).